# Disable Credit Card in Paypal mobile SDK

Tags: android, paypal, sdk, credit-card

I have integrated Paypal mobile SDK in Android. As my account is not able to use direct credit card payment. Our customers failed to pay with credit card button.
May I know how to disable/remove the credit card button in my App.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding how to remove credit card option, you may set acceptCreditCards as false in the PaypalConfiguration object:

For example:

```
private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        …….
        .acceptCreditCards(false)
        .merchantName("Hipster Store")
        .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
        .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));
```

Note:
acceptCreditCards(boolean acceptCreditCards):  Optional boolean to indicate support for credit cards.

[Mobile SDK Java Doc](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/gh-pages/index.html)

Above setting will help you to disable/remove credit card option in  your App.